# Org-Mode Tags inside text instead of Headline

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a half-made latex presentation in a org-mode file. I want to insert tags in paragraphs which are incomplete. Something along these lines,

`* Related Work`

Prior work was done by ... :incomplete:

Is this possible?

Comment: The regexp for tags is based upon them being in the header (first line).  There are many functions that might need to be rewritten if you wanted to create a search based upon a tag in an unusual location, or highlighting in an unusual location (depending upon the function, which may or may not use font-lock).

Comment: Maybe *inline tasks* can help you. You can add TODO items, with tags, while not affecting your outline.

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be in transforming your plain lists or lines to headlines

```
* Prior work was done by ... :incomplete:
```

and use following line into the .org file header

```
#+OPTIONS: H:2 num:2
```

that describes to which level headlines are enumerated and included into table of contents.